# Query MongoDB nested document and find the exact matching inner object with having one of its filters taking its own field value as condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the below document in a Mongo collection.

```
{
   "_id":"112211",
   "student":{
      "student_display_name":"Siva",
      "first_name":"Siva",
      "last_name":"Ram",
      "age":"20",
      "department":"IT",
      "section":"D",
      "edit_sequence":"2",
      "unique_id":"siva_2",
      "address":{
         "data":[
            {
               "student_display_name":"Siva",
               "first_name":"Siva",
               "last_name":"Ram",
               "student_id":"siva_2",
               "street":"Perter's Park",
               "area":"BMS Road",
               "pincode":"560001"
            },
            {
               "student_display_name":"Siva",
               "first_name":"Siva",
               "last_name":"Ram",
               "student_id":"siva_1",
               "street":"St.Mary's Colony",
               "area":"BMS Road",
               "pincode":"560001"
            },
            {
               "student_display_name":"Siva",
               "first_name":"Siva",
               "last_name":"Ram",
               "student_id":"siva_0",
               "street":"MG Colony",
               "area":"BMS Road",
               "pincode":"560001"
            }
         ]
      },
      "student":{
         "data":[
            {
               "student_display_name":"Siva",
               "first_name":"Siva",
               "last_name":"Ram",
               "age":"20",
               "department":"IT",
               "section":"B",
               "edit_sequence":"1",
               "unique_id":"siva_1"
            },
            {
               "student_display_name":"Siva",
               "first_name":"Siva",
               "last_name":"Ram",
               "age":"20",
               "department":"IT",
               "section":"A",
               "edit_sequence":"0",
               "unique_id":"siva_0"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "college":"student college",
   "root_table":"student"
}
```

From this document, I need to query using the following match filters.

```
{
   "$match":{
      "$or":[
         {
            "student.address.data.pincode":"560001"
         },
         {
            "$and":[
               {
                  "student.address.data.data.last_name":"Siva"
               },
               {
                  "student.address.data.data.first_name":"Ram"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

With these match filters, Further,
We will get all the 3 objects under **address.data** array.
But, from these results I want to filter even further based on "**student.unique_id like student.address.data.student_id = student.unique_id**" value, so that I will get only one match as below.

This is the final result which I want.

```
 {
       "address":{
                   "student_display_name":"Siva",
                   "first_name":"Siva",
                   "last_name":"Ram",
                   "student_id":"siva_2",
                   "street":"Perter's Park",
                   "area":"BMS Road",
                   "pincode":"560001"
                }
    }
```

How to achieve this in MongoDB?

Comment: **I want to filter even further based on "student.unique_id" value** if you want to search by unique id then why need other conditions like `first_name`, `last_name` and  `pincode`?

Comment: @turivishal the scenario is, there are 3 student objects with different versions. The latest version is with unique_id as siva_2.
For each version, the address can also vary.
So, I want to query in a manner, select all students address with latest version given first_name, last_name and pincode.

If it is in relational database, we will query like the below.
select  a.* from student s inner join address a on a.pincode = s.pincode
where a.unique_id = (select max(sequence) from student)

Comment: Just curious, even though u have 3 versions, u have `unique_id` which is unique among all documents and version, right? You you can easliy filter it by `unique_id` no? if Im not mistaken

Comment: Like this I will have n number of documents. As per the requirement, I need to find out based on 'pincode' and with that pincode get it with the latest version.

Comment: I can't use unique_id because, from the application it will pass only pincode and first_name & last_name as filter parameters. so  unique_id I should get from max sequence of student object which is "unique_id":"siva_2". This is the structure of our json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nota:** If your `student.address.data` contains only the same student data, you can omit filtering twice in the second stage.

Documentation: [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/)

#### Pseudocode

```
reduce(input, initial={student_id: '${student.unique_id}'}, condition)
    value = initial
    for this in input:
        if this.pincode == '...'
           AND this.last_name == '...'
           AND this.first_name == '...'
           AND this.student_id == value.student_id:
           value = this
        else:
           value = value
    return value
```

Try this one:

```
db.student.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "$and": [
        {
          "student.address.data.pincode": "560001"
        },
        {
          "student.address.data.last_name": "Ram"
        },
        {
          "student.address.data.first_name": "Siva"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "address": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$student.address.data",
          initialValue: {
            student_id: "$student.unique_id"
          },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: [ "$$this.pincode", "560001" ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [ "$$this.first_name", "Siva" ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [ "$$this.last_name", "Ram" ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [ "$$value.student_id", "$$this.student_id" ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jcqzc3gIYbN)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you please give me some explanation on each progress within $reduce. Wanted to understand the solution.

Comment: @Jerin Check again, now it should be clear how reduce works in this case

Comment: I can understand the Psuedo code. Basically we are looping over the array and comparing with the condition.  
I Have 2 questions. 


1. How this condition is achieved "student.address.data.student_id = student.unique_id" 


2.  if this.pincode == '...' 
AND this.unique_id > value.unique_id: 
value = this 
else: value = value 
return value 

Here, which part of $reduce does this assigning value and returning the value.

Comment: @Jerin check again. Assignment happens in `$cond:[condition, true_result, false_result]`

Comment: Ohh.. I get it now. Thanks a lot Valijon

Comment: One more doubt I have. Here what these 2 variable holds $$this & $$value.
As per my understanding, $$this, will have current iteration of array which is being processed i.e student.address.data[index] array.
Not getting what $$value means and what it holds

Comment: @Jerin Correct. `$$value` has initial value or last matched `student.address.data[index]`.